# Fourier coefficients of positive polynomials

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $p(x) \geq 0$ be a positive polynomial on the hypersphere ($x \in S^{n-1}$) satisfying $\int_{S^{n-1}} p(x) = 1$. Writing $p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^s p_j(x)$ where $p_j(x) = \sum_m p_{jm} s_{jm}(x)$ with $s_{jm}(x)$ being the spherical harmonics of degree $j$ normalized to $\int_{S^{n-1}} s_{jm}(x)^2 = 1$, the last condition just says that the lowest order Fourier coefficient is $p_0 = 1$.

Are there any bounds known on the components $p_j(x)$ using that $p(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$? Or the Fourier coefficients $p_{jm}$?

It is possible to obtain some easy bounds on $p_{jm}$ in terms of the maxima of $s_{jm}(x)$ but I am looking for sharper bounds on $p_j(x)$ combined. It is also possible to get a bound on $p_j(x)$ in terms of the maxima of the Gegenbauer polynomials, but again I am hoping for sharper bounds.

Many thanks for your advise!

Comment: What do you mean by "for all x"? X-s on the sphere or everywhere in R^n?

Comment: Just on the sphere